# Facebook Fanbox widget in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

can any one help me out for "Integration of Facebook Fanbox widget" into an iPhone how can i integrate facebook fanbox into my iphone application? any suggestion or help and code will be appreciated

i know about this link but how to integrate this for iPhone app that i don't know

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you haven't provided a great deal of information about how you would like to achieve this, all I can suggest is going to the link you listed above and using the tool to generate the html code you need.

Then create a uiwebview on your viewcontroller and use

```
[webView loadHTMLString:html];
```

Where webview is the webview you added and html is an NSString with a value of the code facebook provided. Alternatively create a local html file that has the facebook code in it and load the file into the webview.